# How to filter pCollection on the first two characters (Python)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I hope someone can help!

I am fairly new to Apache Beam, Cloud Dataflow, and what I would like to do is

1. Read GZIP File Contents
2. File is fixed width
3. Filter said contents based on first two characters to another pCollection

What I have so far:

--PAR DO Function

```
class FilterHeader(beam.DoFn):
def process(self, element):
    if element[:2] == '01':
        yield element
    else:
        return 'Header Not found' # Return nothing - this was blank, as I was just trying to view in the return came back with anything if not the row
```

And my pipeline is as follows

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)) as p:
# Initial PCollection Full File
rows = (
    p | 'Read daily Spot File' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(
                file_pattern='gs://<my bucket>/filename.gz', 
                compression_type='gzip',
                coder=coders.BytesCoder(),
                skip_header_lines=0))
# Header Collection - filtered on first two characters = 01
header_collection = (
    rows    | 'Filter Record Type 01 to our HEADER COLLECTION' >> beam.ParDo(FilterHeader())
            | 'Output Header Rows' >> beam.io.WriteToText('gs://<destination bucket>/new_fileName.txt'))
```

When I remove the filter, I can output all the rows so there isn't anything wrong with the file, or the initial pCollection. Once I add in the filter, the rows I am after do not come out. And yes, the data is present in the file i.e. there is one row which starts with 01 as the first characters.

Is there something simple I am missing?

Any direction greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hm this should work.. just reproduced it on my end. Maybe there's a whitespace in front of 01 in your file? Can you try with `if '01' in element`?

Comment: Yes, I suspect this is some sort of a string mismatch. I suggest confirming that if condition get hit by printing a log.

Comment: Ok - thanks for your feedback. Much appreciated. I'll try printing the first two characters to see what shows up in the logs.

Comment: I did wonder whether the element itself passed is actually a list, so I've changed the if statement slightly so that it reads str(element[0])[:2] - I did change this to str(element[:2]) as it logged a type error i.e. it thought element was type int. Possibly because the file is in bytes?

Comment: This did the trick...`row = str(element.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
        if row[:2] == '01':
            yield element`